# Wrap/overwrite function in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How could I rewrite `echo` to print some character before anything I pass to it?

I was thinking about something like this which does not work:

```
alias oldecho=echo
echo(){oldecho ==> $1}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close.

```
echo() { builtin echo "==>" "$@"; }
```

`builtin` forces the rest of the command to be executed as a builtin, which simplifies reimplementing builtins.

Your problem, though, was not quoting the `>`.

Comment: how could I put an enter before the arrow?

Comment: +1 for use of `builtin` and spotting the problem with unquoted `==>`. @juanpastas: Use `$'\n==>`' or precede the `builtin` command with `printf '\n'`, or even another `builtin echo`.

Comment: echo -ne "\n==>" will prepend a newline

Comment: @juanpastas: In addition to the other suggestions, the simple way is to just hit the enter key right after you type the first `"` (that is, before the `"` and the first `=`).

Comment: This only works in the special case that you're wrapping a "function" that is a built-in command. Actually wrapping a function of the same name isn't addressed.

Comment: @buzkor: the question was specifically about `echo`, which qualifies (in bash, at least), so I don't think the answer was wrong. Moreover, it says "builtins".

Comment: @Jeff, `echo -ne` (like `echo -n`, `echo -e`, and to a lesser extent `echo` as a whole) is extremely unreliable. Even if you're 100% sure your shell is bash, there are a bunch of configuration knobs that can change its behavior at runtime; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819 and the POSIX echo spec

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but maybe this will help...

`alias echo='/bin/echo ==\> $*'`

...where I'm assuming `==>` are the characters you always want prepended.

(note the backslash `\`, which you need to prevent the `>` from being interpreted as a redirect.)

Comment: But `echo` is almost always invoked as a shell built-in command, rarely calling out to `/bin/echo`. Particularly in bash, as the OP is asking about.

Comment: So change it to `builtin echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat inspired by Python decorators, here's a function I've written to allow wrapping bash functions, built-in commands and calls to executables. I have it in my .bashrc file.

```bash
# bashwrap function: given a function name and code to run before and/or after,
# wrap the existing function with the code that comes before and after.  The
# before and after code is taken literally and eval'd, so it can do things like
# access "$@" and indeed change "$@" by using shift or set or similar.
bashwrap () {
    local command beforecode aftercode type unset_extglob n
    local innerfuncname innerfunccode
    local -n varname

    command="$1"
    beforecode="$2"
    aftercode="$3"

    # Check the current state of extglob: this code needs it to be set,
    # but it should be reset to avoid unexpected changes to the global
    # envirnoment.
    if ! shopt -q extglob; then
        unset_extglob=YesPlease
        shopt -s extglob
    fi

    # Tidy the before and after code: trim whitespace from the start and end,
    # and make sure they end with a single semicolon.
    for varname in beforecode aftercode; do
        varname="${varname##+([$'\n\t '])}"
        varname="${varname%%+([$'\n\t '])}"
        if [[ "$varname" ]]; then
            varname="${varname%%+(;)};"
        fi
    done

    # Now finished with extglob.
    if [[ "$unset_extglob" ]]; then shopt -u extglob; fi

    type="$(type -t "$command")"
    case "$type" in
        alias)
            printf "bashwrap doesn't (yet) know how to handle aliases\n" >&2
            return 69  # EX_UNAVAILABLE
            ;;
        keyword)
            printf 'bashwrap cannot wrap Bash keywords\n' >&2
            return 64  # EX_USAGE
            ;;
        builtin|file)
            eval "$command () { $beforecode command $command \"\$@\"; $aftercode }"
            ;;
        function)
            # Keep generating function names until we get to one that doesn't
            # exist.  This allows a function to be wrapped multiple times; the
            # original function will always have the name
            # _bashwrapped_0_<name>.
            n=0
            innerfuncname="_bashwrapped_${n}_$command"
            while declare -Fp -- "$innerfuncname" &>/dev/null; do
                innerfuncname="_bashwrapped_$((++n))_$command"
            done

            # Define a new function with the new function name and the old function
            # code.
            innerfunccode="$(declare -fp -- "$command")"
            eval "${innerfunccode/#$command /$innerfuncname }"

            # Redefine the existing function to call the new function, in
            # between the wrapper code.
            eval "$command () { $beforecode $innerfuncname \"\$@\"; $aftercode }"
            ;;
        '')
            printf 'Nothing called %q found to wrap\n' "$command" >&2
            return 64  # EX_USAGE
            ;;
        *)
            printf 'Unexpected object type %s\n' "$type" >&2
            return 70  # EX_SOFTWARE
            ;;
    esac
}
```

The simple case in the original question can then be handled as below; using `command` to avoid the `echo` call from calling the function we're creating.

```bash
$ bashwrap echo 'command echo -n "==> "'
$ echo 'Hello, world!'
==> Hello, world!
```

You can use `type` to see what's happening under the covers:

```bash
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ bashwrap echo 'command echo "==> "'
$ type echo
echo is a function
echo ()
{
    command echo "==> ";
    command echo "$@"
}
```

This also allows much more complex wrapping, including repeatedly wrapping functions:

```bash
$ bashwrap echo 'command echo earlier' 'command echo later'
$ bashwrap echo 'command echo earliest'
$ bashwrap echo '' 'command echo latest'
$ echo 'Hello, world!'
earliest
earlier
Hello, world!
later
latest
```