# How to write a bash function to wrap another command?

Tags: mysql, bash, function

I am trying to write a function wrapper for the `mysql` command

If `.my.cnf` exists in the pwd, I would like to automatically attach `--defaults-file=.my.cnf` to the command

Here's what I'm trying

```
function mysql {
  if [ -e ".my.cnf" ]; then
    /usr/local/bin/mysql --defaults-file=.my.cnf "$@"
  else
    /usr/local/bin/mysql "$@"
  fi
}
```

The idea is, I want to be able to use the `mysql` command *exactly* as I was before, only, if the `.my.cnf` file is present, attach it as an argument

**Question:** Will I run into any trouble with this method? Is there a better way to do it?

If I specify `--defaults-file=foo.cnf` manually, that should be used instead of `.my.cnf`.

Comment: You should use `"$@"`. Also what happens if `--defaults-file` is already in the arguments to the function? What does mysql do if it gets that twice? I assume it probably uses the last one on the command line. In that case which of the arguments do you want to win? Yours or the one in the arguments?

Comment: @EtanReisner, if `--defaults-file` is specified, it should be used. How can I accommodate for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function as written is perfectly fine. This is a touch DRYer:

```
function mysql {
    if [ -e ".my.cnf" ]; then
        set -- --defaults-file=.my.cnf "$@"
    fi
    /usr/local/bin/mysql "$@"
}
```

That `set` command puts your my.cnf argument at the beginning of the command line arguments

Only if the option is not already present:

```
function mysql {
    if [[ -e ".my.cnf" && "$*" != *"--defaults-file"* ]]; then
        set -- --defaults-file=.my.cnf "$@"
    fi
    /usr/local/bin/mysql "$@"
}
```

Comment: Can I make it only attach `--defaults-file=.my.cnf` if it's not already specified ?

Comment: You can loop through `$@` to see if an argument matches but the better question to ask is do you need to bother. Like I said in my comment, if `mysql` accepts that argument multiple times and just always uses the last one it gets then you don't have to do anything more than this.

Comment: If you are checking that `--defaults-file` is already used, keep in mind that the `=` is optional and may not be used in the original call.

Comment: @chepner, accomodated.

Comment: `mysql` will complain if two `--defaults-file` flags are set. I updated the second part of the if condition to `"$*" != *"--defaults-file"*` to resolve this issue. Instead of specifically checking for `--deftauls-file=.my.cnf`, this matches things like `--defaults-file=whatever.cnf`, or any file chosen by the user.

Comment: @glennjackman, wups. I might've just clobbered one of your edits while working on a stale version of your answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: I wanted to solve a similar problem, and have written a generic solution for wrapping Bash commands at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77416895/220155. With the code there, you could implement the above solution as `bashwrap mysql '[[ -e .my.cnf && "$*" != $"--defaults-file"* ]] && set -- --defaults-file=.my.cnf "$@"`. Not worth it if this is the only time you want to wrap a call from Bash, but might be more useful if it's something you want to do semi-regularly.