# How to "wrap" a bash command and parse arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I found this question: [How to write a bash function to wrap another command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373595/how-to-write-a-bash-function-to-wrap-another-command)

And it kind of answered my question but not quite..

I want to do something similar to the above, but set an environment variable depending on arguments to the command - the argument parsing is where I'm stuck

I want to wrap `docker-compose` in a function and if it's `up` then set an env variable that stores the directory of the docker-compose.yml file; if it's down, then unset the env var.

```
function docker-compose () {

  if "$@" == "*up*"; then
    DC_FILE=${$PWD##*/}
  elif "$@" == "*down*"; then
    unset DC_FILE
  fi
  command docker-compose "$@"
}
```

Something like that but the argument parsing is what's got me stuck

abstractly:

```
function fun() {
if the arguments contain "a":
 set var
elif the arguments contain "b":
 unset var
fi
execute command with all arguments passed to it
}
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, did you receive an error?

Comment: $ docker-compose up -d
-bash: up: command not found
-bash: up: command not found

Comment: I am intentionally unfamiliar with docker, but when setting environment variables, you must understand setting the variables can only effect the current script and subshells spawned beneath it, it can never effect the environment of the parent process. Presuming you are setting the environment for `command docker-compose "$@"` and that writes some environment variable to be used by some later process, that is fine, but from your question I cannot tell if that is the ultimate case or not.

Comment: I don't need the variable to be used by docker at all, just setting it for me as I jump between different directories that all have their own docker-compose files and sometimes I'll try to "down" docker with a different docker-compose than I "up" it with that causes some issues. This is more of an admin thing for myself. For my issue, the command that's in the function can be arbitrary..

I edited the question to be more abstract

Comment: How are you using the script?
executing it? or adding this to some init file like bashrc?

Comment: Wanting it to be a function in `.bashrc` and execute anytime I use the `docker-compose` command

Comment: @MitchWilson: (1) You have quotes around your wildcard characters, so wildcard matching is not done. `[[ "$@" == *up* ]]`would do. (2) You don't set an **environment variable**, but a **shell variable*. Environment variables can be set by `export NAME=VALUE`. (3) If someone calls your function as `docker_compose xxupyy down`, it would be interpreted as _up_. Is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

To check if the list of arguments contain a substring, you can use

```
if [[ "$*" == *"up"* ]]
then
  echo "Match"
fi
```

This uses the extended test command`[[ .. ]]` to match `"$*"` (arguments joined with spaces into a single string) with the glob pattern `*"up"*`. It therefore matches `up foo` and `down --project-name=backup`

Comment: Thanks for the help with regex matching.. using that I think I got it working

`function docker-compose () {
    local pwd=$(pwd)
    pwd=${pwd##*/}
    if [[ "$@" == *"up"* ]]; then
        export DC_FILE=$pwd
    elif [[ "$@" == *"down"* ]]; then
        unset DC_FILE
    fi
    command docker-compose "$@"
}`

Comment: @MitchWilson : There are no regex involved in your code.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, extglobs are regexes

Comment: I'm not sure the proper term when referencing '*' in the shell. I intended to thank for the help in where to put `", *, $ `